# Jquery/javascript way send 50 forms as if it was 1 form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is there a Jquery way to send 50 forms as if it was 1 form?

```
<form><input name="1"></form>
<form><input name="2"></form>
<form><input name="3"></form>
<form><input name="4"></form>
```

as if it was:

```
<form><input name="1">
<input name="2">
<input name="3">
<input name="4"></form>
```

sending it like this object including all inputs:

```
document.forms[0]
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you would want this..

Comment: I'm making a form in the google web app (google apps script deploy web app). The form had many inputs (50+) and runs very slow on Ipad's Safari.

As discussed on stackoverflow the solution is to make 50+ seperate form tags surrounding each input, but Google web app does not allow to have multiple form inputs to run to the script side (google.script.run). This way i can send one form element to apps script, having solved the ipad form issue :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a new single form that contains the 50 other forms values:

```
var $form = $(document.createElement('form'));
$('form :input').clone().appendTo($form);
```

Now, `$form` contains all of the inputs.

Comment: Wow you make it look so easy, gonna check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Send form data by serialize it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>36373219</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form class="form" id="f1" >
            <input name="f1_inp_1" value="1">
            <input name="f1_inp_2" value="2">
        </form>

        <form class="form" id="f2" >
            <input name="f2_inp_1" value="1">
            <input name="f2_inp_2" value="2">
        </form>

        <form class="form" id="f3" >
            <input name="f3_inp_1" value="1">
            <input name="f3_inp_2" value="2">
        </form>

        <button id="fire">Fire</button>

    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#fire').on('click', preparesend);

        function preparesend(event)
        {
            sendform(event);
        }

        function sendform(event){

            event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
            event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

            var data = new FormData();

            $('form').each(function(key,value) {

                data.append( key, $(this).serialize());

            });
            $.ajax({
                url: 'get_response.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```